# CORS issues when adding atatus to ionic project

Tags: angularjs, cors, ionic-framework, atatus

I am trying to add [Atatus](https://www.atatus.com) to my Ionic project. I followed the [documentation](https://www.atatus.com/docs) to include the scripts.

**FIRST TRY**

So my `index.html` includes the scripts like this:

```
<script src="https://dmc1acwvwny3.cloudfront.net/atatus.js" crossorigin="anonymous" type="application/javascript" />
<script type="text/javascript"> atatus.config('MY_API_KEY').install(); </script>
```

In the documentation they mention [CORS issues](https://www.atatus.com/docs/enabling-cors) and how to solve them. The header is something I can't set if I am correct, this header should be set on the cloudfront server. So I have added the `crossorigin` attribute in the script tag, but still I receive the CORS error when running the project locally with `ionic serve`:

```
Script from origin 'https://dmc1acwvwny3.cloudfront.net' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://192.168.178.59:8100' is therefore not allowed access.
```

**SECOND TRY**

Then I tried to solve the CORS issues with adding proxies in the `ionic.project` file according to this [blog post](http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/) from Ionic. So my `ionic.project` file contains:

```
{
  "name": "my-amazing-app",
  "app_id": "345gfsd3trf",
  "gulpStartupTasks": [
    "build:env",
    "build:index",
    "build:sass",
    "build:template",
    "build:js",
    "concat:index",
    "watch"
  ],
  "proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/atatus.js",
      "proxyUrl": "https://dmc1acwvwny3.cloudfront.net/atatus.js"
    }
  ]
}
```

So I changed the `index.html` to use this proxy:

```
<script src="http://localhost:8100/atatus.js" crossorigin="anonymous" type="application/javascript" />
<script type="text/javascript"> atatus.config('MY_API_KEY').install(); </script>
```

When I start serving with `ionic serve` the output looks promising:

```
me@my-laptop:~/Documents/Projects/my-amazing-app$ ionic serve
Gulp startup tasks: [ 'build:env',
  'build:index',
  'build:sass',
  'build:template',
  'build:js',
  'concat:index',
  'watch' ]
Running live reload server: http://192.168.178.59:35729
Watching : [ 'www/**/*', '!www/lib/**/*' ]
Proxy added: /atatus.js => https://dmc1acwvwny3.cloudfront.net/atatus.js
Running dev server: http://192.168.178.59:8100
Ionic server commands, enter:
  restart or r to restart the client app from the root
  goto or g and a url to have the app navigate to the given url
  consolelogs or c to enable/disable console log output
  serverlogs or s to enable/disable server log output
  quit or q to shutdown the server and exit
```

But unfortunally I receive a connection refused in the console: `GET http://localhost:8100/atatus.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

**THIRD TRY**

I thought maybe this is because of the use of `localhost` instead of my internal IP `192.168.178.59`. So I changed all use of `localhost` to `192.168.178.59`, but then I get a `403 Forbidden`.

**FOURTH TRY**

The last test I did was adding `atatus` library locally through bower:

```
bower install atatus-js
```

Also changed the `index.html` accordingly:

```
<script src="lib/atatus-js/atatus.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous" type="application/javascript" />
<script type="text/javascript"> atatus.config('MY_API_KEY').install(); </script>
```

Now I receive no errors when loading the library, but when I trough an notify to atatus manually through the console: `atatus.notify(new Error('Test Atatus Setup'));` I receive the following errors from `atatus.min.js`:

```
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.178.59:3001/socket.io/socket.io.js. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://192.168.178.59:8100' is therefore not allowed access.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'test' of undefined(…)
```

Which I don't understand. Why is it complaining about `http://192.168.178.59:3001/socket.io/socket.io.js`. This is my local running `socket.io` server, which runs correctly and has CORS configured. Without `atatus` added the whole project runs perfectly with these sockets.

**FIFTH TRY**

I have deployed the project with the fourth try to a DigitalOcean server. So the `atatus` library is loaded locally (bower). No CORS issues arise, but I receive the following error when adding a notify in the console:

```
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'test' of undefined(…)
```

**SOLUTION**

I had to change 2 settings, being:

- Set the next: `$.ajaxPrefilter(function( options, originalOptions, jqXHR ) {options.async = true;});`
- Add `https://*.atatus.com` to the `default-src` of the `Content-Security-Policy` meta header.

Comment: What is version number in your local atatus(fifth try)? (you can see it in top of the atatus.js file).  FYI, we did not use XMLHttpRequest for sending payload to our server. We just uses image script tag for sending payload.

Comment: This is the version information from `atatus.min.js` installed through `bower` in the fifth try: ` AtatusJs - v2.2.5 - 2015-09-01`

Comment: I tried :(. But i could not reproduce the issue. Can you try 

`$.ajaxPrefilter(function( options, originalOptions, jqXHR ) {options.async = true;});`

Comment: The `Synchronous XMLHttpRequest` message is gone, but the `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'test' of undefined` still errors

Comment: Okay. Good. Can you add debugMode option to see any payload sending to atatus server?  `atatus.config('MY_API_KEY', { debugMode: true } ).install();`

when you calling `atatus.notify(new Error('Test Atatus Setup'));`, it should print sending payload and you can also see the request in network panel.

Comment: With the debug option enable I saw the error. Since Cordova 5.x you need to specify the `Content-Security-Policy` meta header. In this header in the `default-src` I have to add `https://*.atatus.com`. Now all works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @MarkVeenstra

Since `Cordova 5.x`, you need to specify the `Content-Security-Policy` meta header. In this header in the `default-src`, you have to add `https://*.atatus.com`. Then all works.